# How to store an image in a variable

Tags: python, html, image, matplotlib

I would like to store the image generated by `matplotlib` in a variable `raw_data` to use it as inline image.

```
import os
import sys
os.environ['MPLCONFIGDIR'] = '/tmp/'
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print "Content-type: image/png\n"
plt.plot(range(10, 20))

raw_data = plt.show()

if raw_data:
    uri = 'data:image/png;base64,' + urllib.quote(base64.b64encode(raw_data))
    print '<img src = "%s"/>' % uri
else:
    print "No data"

#plt.savefig(sys.stdout, format='png')
```

None of the functions suit my use case:

- `plt.savefig(sys.stdout, format='png')` - Writes it to stdout. This does help.. as I have to embed the image in a html file.
- `plt.show()` / `plt.draw()` does nothing when executed from command line

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Have you tried `cStringIO` or an equivalent?

```
import os
import sys
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import StringIO
import urllib, base64

plt.plot(range(10, 20))
fig = plt.gcf()

imgdata = StringIO.StringIO()
fig.savefig(imgdata, format='png')
imgdata.seek(0)  # rewind the data

print "Content-type: image/png\n"
uri = 'data:image/png;base64,' + urllib.quote(base64.b64encode(imgdata.buf))
print '<img src = "%s"/>' % uri
```

Comment: Thanks.. That helped... 
I was hoping there would be a way to directly get the image  instead of using a file handle..

Comment: @Ramya:  StringIO does not use filehandles.  It is all in-memory storage and there is no OS limit to the number of StringIO instances:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177230/python-about-file-handle-limits-on-os

Comment: Don't forget to unquote the string before decoding, because I got some 'Incorrect padding' errors because of the url encoding.

Comment: FYI, in Python 3 you'll need to use io.BytesIO, eg: `buf = io.BytesIO(); plt.gcf().savefig(buf, format='png'); buf.seek(0); return base64.b64encode(buf.read())`

Comment: Instead of a plot, I have a 2d matrix. How do I return it as JPG image data as a variable? I was hoping `imsave` had a "return" kind of option.

Answer (score 23):

Complete python 3 version, putting together [Paul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5314808/1192542) and [metaperture's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314707/matplotlib-store-image-in-variable/5314808#comment51401519_5314808).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import io
import urllib, base64

plt.plot(range(10))
fig = plt.gcf()

buf = io.BytesIO()
fig.savefig(buf, format='png')
buf.seek(0)
string = base64.b64encode(buf.read())

uri = 'data:image/png;base64,' + urllib.parse.quote(string)
html = '<img src = "%s"/>' % uri
```

Comment: Hi, is there any way around the very long urls?