# save pyplot generated image in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, matplotlib, pymongo

I am trying to save plots generated by pyplot in mongodb. I could save them as files, then save the files as entries in the db, but is there a cleaner way of just saving the plot object and then retrieving and displaying it (from python code)?

Comment: Maybe you can store it in base64, as this SO question explains http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314707/matplot-store-image-in-variable

Comment: "Cleaner"? That's quite subjective. What's wrong with saving the files?

Comment: do you want to save this as pickled `figure` objects or as a `png`, `pdf`,.. ?

Comment: pickled `figure` would be preferable, but png is also an acceptable solution.